# In Dialogflow fulfilment is there a way for one response to be randomly returned from a list of multiple potential responses?

Tags: dialogflow-es

In the Intent tab when creating an intent there is a "Responses" section and you can add multiple responses and one will be picked at random to respond to the user.

Using the inline editor in fulfilment calling:

```
agent.add("send a response back");
```

Sends a command back to the user but I was wondering if I can set this up so that just like in the Intent screen the response to be sent back will be one picked from a list of multiple responses:

eg.

```
agent.add("response1");
agent.add("response2");
agent.adD("response3");
```

and one of these will randomly be sent back.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although varying responses is considered best practice for VUI design, there is no direct way to do this.

However, the best way to approach this problem is to have the possible replies in an array, and then picking one of them randomly. Something like this:

```
var possibleResponse = [
  'Response 1',
  'Response 2',
  'Response 3'
];

var pick = Math.floor( Math.random() * possibleResponse.length );

var response = possibleResponse[pick];
agent.add( response );
```

This is also better because when you go to internationalize your Action, you can just replace the `possibleResponse` with localized strings.

In fact, this was such a popular approach to the problem, that the [multivocal](https://multivocal.info/) library made it the core of its solution.  You just provide the possible localized responses for an Action, Intent, or Outent in the configuration and it takes care of picking one for you. And since all the responses are templates, you can add whatever other parameters you want or put conditions on displaying them (such as handling singular or plural values). So in multivocal, this part of the configuration would be:

```
Local: {
  en: {
    Response: {
      "Intent.welcome": [
        "Response 1",
        "Response 2",
        "Response 3"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Does index.js in the inline editor get run each time something is sent to fulfilment? I know it's not best practice but I tried using a global variable to store something outside of the exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment function for reuse but it didn't quite work and i'm assuming index.js is run each time something is sent to fulfilment. Thx.

Comment: I'd need to know more about what you're doing with it and why, and some sample code of what you're trying would help, too. That sounds like it would be better asked as a new question in Stack Overflow.

Comment: This is very strange because in the inline editor  it seems to work fine.