# How to make random image response

Tags: json, dialogflow-es

i need help about dialogflow json script.. i want to show a random image that i already hosting as a line response from certain word..

This is a dialogflow code i downloaded.. i try some but didnt work.

```
  "responses": [
    {
      "resetContexts": false,
      "affectedContexts": [],
      "parameters": [],
      "messages": [
       {
          "type": 3,
          "platform": "line",
          "imageUrl": "https://i.ibb.co/2Kb9hWV/Somepics-001.png",
          "lang": "en"
        }
      ],
      "defaultResponsePlatforms": {},
      "speech": []
    }
  ],
```

i want the result to showing pics randomly from image i hosted like https://i.ibb.co/2Kb9hWV/Somepics-001.png
https://i.ibb.co/2Kb9hWV/otherpics-001.png
https://i.ibb.co/2Kb9hWV/pics-201.png

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In Dialogflow fulfilment is there a way for one response to be randomly returned from a list of multiple potential responses?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51221495/in-dialogflow-fulfilment-is-there-a-way-for-one-response-to-be-randomly-returned)

Comment: When you say it "didn't work", it would help us help you a lot if you provided more information. Did you get an error message? How did you test that it didn't work? This is JSON - how are you generating this JSON and sending it? Can you show us that code? Screen shots of testing it? Please update the question with as much as you can provide.

Comment: in dialogflow.. we can create intent with template, download and upload it. so i create one intent with template, and download it..  that code is from that intent, but i want to mod it to random image.
ill try look at @elias link..